# Definition Of Open Subsets Of Metric Spaces

Tags: general-topology

I want to know that if there is a metric space $(X, d)$ and an open subset $A \subset X$ and if we change the metric from $d$ to say $d'$, then is it possible that $A$ will be no longer an open subset of $X$. Can someone please give me an example??

Comment: Consider $R$  with discrete metric then every subset is open, If I change to euclidean metric then it is not true.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the discrete metric: $d(x,y) = 1$ if $x\neq y$. This gives the discrete topology, and obviously differs from that of the standard topology on $\mathbb R ^n$.